# wordpress redirect to subdomain after login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my  wordpress blog at `www.mysite.com` , also I have my own php application at a subdomain `l.mysite.com`

I want the login credentials of WordPress in my PHP application. I figured out that by including the `wp-blog-header.php` from the root to my app.

I can use the user info OK.

I wanted to redirect users to `www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=l.mysite.com` . You can see here that I am specifying the `redirect_to` parameter. Wordpress ignores this and redirects to admin panel.

I  think that worpdress doesn't allow redirect to an "external domain" , which I think is specified in `wp_safe_redirect()` function in wordpress. Is there any plugin which could ignore some domain to which redirect can happen?

I see that there are many login specific redirect plugins but none which could do to a new doamin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Plugin: http://www.theblog.ca/wplogin-redirect

Looks like it does what you want. Probably it's outdated, however, it should be trivial to create a plugin that fits your need.

A filter to start with is `login_redirect`, there is another filter in `wp_safe_redirect()` so you can prevent the domain you want to use being blocked.

To monitor redirects, checkout my [Better HTTP Redirects Plugin](http://hakre.wordpress.com/plugins/better-http-redirects/).

Comment: I already know know about peter's redirect plugin. I needed the redirects according to role , but also enable me to redirect to any other domain other then my blog's . let me see if that plugin can do a external domain redirect else i will add my own exception is 'wp-login.php'

Comment: @karanits: As an alternative, you can filter the login redirect as well to go always to the page you need if it's an always on option. That probably is even safer as you take care that the application exactly does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @hakre . I don't have 15 rep so I can't upvote. Repost incase his

```
function cleanup_allowed_redirect_hosts( $hosts )
{
    $allowed_hosts = array('first.domain.com', 'second.domain.com', 'etc.domain.com');
    return array_merge( $hosts, $allowed_hosts );
}

add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'cleanup_allowed_redirect_hosts', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to redirect to subdomain but I was getting no redirection until I've added allowed_redirect_hosts filter !!! THANKS !!!!